# Select language of keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, textview, uitextfield

I am making app with default spanish language. In email form I want show english keyboard. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot control the language of the keyboard. The user chooses which keyboards they would like available via the settings application and can toggle between them using the globe icon on the keyboard. When the keyboard is opened it will open to the most recently used keyboard.check this like http://iphone.appstorm.net/how-to/change-your-keyboard-or-display-language-in-ios/
**You can make a customize keyboard. take a UIView add UIButton and add what you want to all in this view.**